# Why isn't HTML::Obliterate obliterating my HTML?

Tags: html, perl, strip

I am trying to use the following code, which I have not been able to test yet, because I get the following errors:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Text::Wrap;
use Mail::Box::Manager;
use HTML::Obliterate qw(extirpate_html);


open (MYFILE, '>>data.txt');
binmode(MYFILE, ':encoding(UTF-8)');


my $file = shift || $ENV{MAIL};
my $mgr = Mail::Box::Manager->new(
    access          => 'r',
);

my $folder = $mgr->open( folder => $file )
or die "$file: Unable to open: $!\n";

for my $msg ( sort { $a->timestamp <=> $b->timestamp } $folder->messages)
{
    my $to          = join( ', ', map { $_->format } $msg->to );
    my $from        = join( ', ', map { $_->format } $msg->from );
    my $date        = localtime( $msg->timestamp );
    my $subject     = $msg->subject;
    my $body        = $msg->decoded->string;


if ( $msg->isMultipart ) {
    foreach my $part ( $msg->parts ) {
        if ( $part->contentType eq 'text/html' ) {
          my $nohtml = extirpate_html( $msg );
$body =~ s/^>.*$//msg;
$Text::Wrap::columns=80;
print MYFILE wrap("", "", <<"");
\n
From: $from
To: $to
Date: $date
Subject: $subject
\n
$body
        }

else {


$body =~ s/^>.*$//msg;
$Text::Wrap::columns=80;
print MYFILE wrap("", "", <<"");
\n
From: $from
To: $to
Date: $date
Subject: $subject
\n
$body

}

}}
```

All the braces seem to match up, so I am unsure what the problem is

```
syntax error at x.pl line 46, near "else"
  (Might be a runaway multi-line << string starting on line 36)
Missing right curly or square bracket at x.pl line 63, at end of line
syntax error at x.pl line 63, at EOF
Execution of x.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

edit:

it now works, but the html is not striped: instead a few emails with stuff like 
> 
> interlaced throughout, causing it to be many more pages than it should. Is there a better way to do this

Comment: Your edit totally changed the nature of the question.. Editing the question should leave original content there if it has already been answered, add clarification to the end instead. Now its a mess.

Comment: You need to make the smallest example possible to illustrate the problem you are having. Try using HTML::Obliterate by isteself without the rest of the task you are trying to do. That makes it easier for others to track down your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So line 36 seems to be

```
print MYFILE wrap("", "", <<"");
```

which means perl will wrap the following text until there is terminator `""` (I never use confusing item like this, I always use END or UNTIL_END for simplicity.)

That terminator is then found on line 45 (the empty line), meaning next thing it processes is line 46:

```
else {
```

which doesn't make sense, since the previous `if` hasn't closed yet (the line 44 which has } is *before* the terminator `""` so its treated as text for wrapping. Perl notices this and kindly suggest you this might be the culprit:

```
(Might be a runaway multi-line << string starting on line 36)
```

You need to swap lines 44 and 45 to first have terminator `""` (empty line), then close the if with `}`. The second wrap in your example does this correctly.

Comment: And the questioner needs to seriously question why it is a good idea to use an invisible terminator, especially since those have caused this question to be asked.

Answer (score 1):

Answer to your modified question:

Instead of extirpating the message body, you extirpate the whole message instead. And then you don't use it anywhere.

```
my $nohtml = extirpate_html( $msg );
$body =~ s/^>.*$//msg;
$Text::Wrap::columns=80;
print MYFILE wrap("", "", <<"");
\n
From: $from
To: $to
Date: $date
Subject: $subject
\n
$body
```

Perhaps you need to change it to:

```
my $nohtml = extirpate_html( $body );
$nohtml =~ s/^>.*$//msg;
```

and then apply the `$nohtml` as the message body for wrap.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I made the changes as you suggested, but there are still ` <BR>` throughout the file

Comment: It just look like the extirpate fails somehow, cannot tell. If nothing else works and the body is otherwise ok to you, add $body =~ s/ <BR>//msg; to remove them.